# Good practice to make AJAX calls in a component, outside of Action Creators?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to make an AJAX call that uploads an image and returns the URL. I don't want/need it to interact with redux's global state. Is it good practice to make the call inside the component?

I'll be uploading multiple images and I don't need the returning URLs to be globally accessible. Should I just follow convention and figure out a way to implement what I want, with AJAX calls only in the action creators?

Comment: You didn't state the reasons for such decision. What effect does having the URL in the global store have on your application? You need Redux middlewares to achieve this. So, how would your store not be aware of the result since you'll be using the `dispatch` method from the `redux store`? 

The only way I see you doing this is doing your AJAX call in your component and not using any `action` which you wouldn't want to do.

Comment: I want to place the URL in a textarea (create Markdown that I can send back to the server as just text). Since it'll be multiple images, the order where these URL are entered matter. Otherwise, I would just store them in an array in global state. @Rowland

Comment: I guess you already have some state that is not in redux (the textarea) or that the textarea is uncontrolled: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html? I personally don't like using uncontrolled components as it somewhat negates the benefits of React. Either way, if the component is what needs to be updated, then whatever you use will need to return the URL to there. No reason you can't make an action creator thunk which does that, but never actually dispatches an action when it executes, but does return data to the dispatching function (usually I use promises)

Comment: Actually, that is exactly what I need. I hadn't reached to storing and submitting the textarea yet. I could just call an action creator to upload the image and dispatch another action to append the image markdown to the textarea's state. Thanks, @dpwrussell

Comment: I would also take a look at redux-form: http://redux-form.com. I find it greatly improves form management.